# Why NSIndexPath length always show 2?

Tags: ios, nsindexpath

I have created a NSIndexPath object but when I print the value of its length property it will always show the value as 2.

```
 NSIndexPath *index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:4];
```

> {length = 2, path = 4 - 0}

Why length is always 2?

Comment: length -> length of the index path itself. 4(first)-0(second).  Anyway this one already covered in answers below.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Because the index path is made of two indexes - the section and the item number.

Comment: thank you! Is there any cases where NSIndexPath having length other than 2?

Comment: It will always be 2 when used with a collection view or table view. But you can use an NSIndexPath for other things as well. So it's possible to have an index path with any number of indexes.

Comment: if you want to change it then it can be done in this manner 
myIndexPath = myIndexPath.indexPathByRemovingLastIndex()

Answer (score 2):

basically `NSIndexPath` is combination of Section and Row, so it will show length as 2.